# Colorbar for Matplotlib 3D patch plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a 3D grid plot in Python using Matplotlib. The grid consists of hexahedral cells (with qudrilateral surfaces). The surfaces should be colored according to their height, that is: the `z` coordinate. A colorbar should accompany the plot.

Here is an example plotting three surfaces:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import numpy as np

def getFaceMidpointsZ(pc):
    a=[]

    for i in pc:
        v=0
        for j in i:
            v=v+j[2]
        v=v/4.
        a.append(v)
    return a

def getColors(m,a):
    b=m.to_rgba(a)
    return [(i[0],i[1],i[2]) for i in b]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
P=[(0,0,0),(2,0,0),(2,2,0),(0,2,0),(0,2,2),(2,2,2),(0,0,2)]
F=[[0,1,2,3],[2,3,4,5],[0,3,4,6]]

x = [t[0] for t in P]
y = [t[1] for t in P]
z = [t[2] for t in P]

pc=[[P[i] for i in f] for f in F]

fz=getFaceMidpointsZ(pc)

q = Poly3DCollection(pc, linewidths=1)
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array([min(z),max(z)])
m.set_clim(vmin=min(z),vmax=max(z))

q.set_facecolor(getColors(m,fz))
ax.add_collection3d(q)

fig.colorbar(m)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_xlim(min(x),max(x))
ax.set_ylim(min(y),max(y))
ax.set_zlim(min(z),max(z))

ax.view_init(elev=18., azim=-43.)
plt.show()
```

I am starting to learn Python and Matplotlib, so any comments would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Coding style

There is an official coding style guide for Python called [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Give it a good read and follow it. For example, the most glaring violations:

- Spacing around operators: instead of `v=v+j[2]`, write as `v = v + j[2]`
- For function names, `snake_case` is preferred over `camelCase`
- Put exactly two blank lines before each function definition

#### Coding practices

Don't put code in the global namespace, put inside a function.
This protects you from bad practices like using global variables, whether intentionally or by accident.

For example, you could move all the code current code in the global namespace inside a `main` function:

```
def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    P = [(0, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 2, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (0, 0, 2)]
    F = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 3, 4, 6]]
    # ...
```

And call the `main` function like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Avoid unused imports:

```
import numpy as np
```

#### Naming

The biggest issue with this code is the naming of variables.
You're overusing single-letter or very short variable names,
and it's hard to guess what is what without searching for where they come from and how they are used.

#### Simplify

You have many expressions that can be simplified, for example:

```
# instead of: v = v + j[2]
v += j[2]

# instead of: v = v / 4.
v /= 4.
```

Comment: You're welcome, meister of `awk` ;-) Btw, it's ok to wait for more comments and accept later, you know...

Comment: Thanks Janos, but I am not using `awk` so much now.. I am moving on to Perl and Python. And I think it is  amazing :)

Comment: Yup, see it in your questions ;-) Glad you like it! Small piece of advice: better `Python` than `Perl`!

Answer (score 0):

> The surfaces should be colored according to their height, that is:
> the z coordinate.

to add colorbar see [exomple code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-surface3d-py) & use [cmap](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/09/colormaps-matplotlib/) param, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
##from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator

# Create 3D plot of the data points and the fitted curve
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# JUST E.G.
# coords of plain fitted
x_range = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
y_range = np.linspace(-2, 2,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
Z = 1.41564 * X**2 + 0.37892 * Y**2 + 2.31836 * X * Y  +  0.10939 * X + 18.55000 *  Y + -1.82745

# plot plain
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', alpha=0.7, cmap=cm.viridis,)   # <<<<<<
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)   # <<<<<<

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].